# print formate text in python

Tags: python, printing

I have a list of text, and I want to output them one by one with a specific format as follows:

```
List=['qwe', 'asdf', 'rftgyhu', 'vbngfr', 'yuo']
```

Desired output:

```
qwe
   asdf
       rftgyhu
              vbngfr
                    yuo
```

The indented space at each line is **exactly** the same as the **sum of the length of previous items**, however, currently, I only have a fixed length of space at each line. I use a function to get the desired result,  but, while I nested it into another function, it works not well, anyone has an easy or simpler idea for implementing this desired result?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `List` as variable name, it's a type

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I have another name in my code, I only use the "List" here as an example:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
words=['qwe', 'asdf', 'rftgyhu', 'vbngfr', 'yuo']
spaces = 0
for i in words:
    print(" " * spaces + i)
    spaces += len(i)
```

What it does is it sets a variable for the spaces. Then it iterates through the list. For each iterate it prints spaces equal to the variable as well as the word. Then it adds the length of the word to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
words=['qwe', 'asdf', 'rftgyhu', 'vbngfr', 'yuo']

spaces = 0
for word in words:
    print(' ' * spaces + word)
    spaces += len(word)
```

https://ideone.com/VdzYXh

Comment: Your code wasn't there yet when I answered. It only appeared when I reloaded the page.
We literally just typed the same solution.

Comment: It's kinda funny, actually :D

Comment: Why else should I copy your code and change the quotation marks to single quotation marks, and the 'i' to 'word'? I was tabbed out and solved it in VSCode, then copy pasted it in. I was kinda confused when your code popped up :D

Comment: But I give you that you were ~10 seconds faster than me, so I give you the win :)

Comment: Thank you both, you two are all very nice!:) :)

Comment: Btw sorry if I was rude. Your comment didn't pop up earlier.

Comment: Don't worry ;) All fine